# Block LOD selection in volume rendering

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering, visualization

I now want to implement flat blocking multi-resolution volume rendering.As we all know,we should first divide the volume data into 2^n*2^n*2^n blocks which has equal size with each other.And then we decide the **LOD(Level of Detail)** of each sub-block.At last we store these blocks using different resolution into a compressed texture.

Now my question is :

(1)I have read a paper 《Multi-resolution texture rendering for medical data》,and I got that the dimension of block must be power of 2.But if the volume data is not power of 2 for example 512*512*225,how should I divide the volume data?

(2)How to calculate the LOD of each blocks?Could someone recommend some typical and useful algorithms to me?

The following is the algorithm in the paper 《Multi-resolution texture rendering for medical data》:
the each level of detail of the block can be quanlified by formula below:

[image]

avgi means the average of the 2^3(max_l) scalar value in the i-th subblock of certain father block.max_l is the highest level of detail of the father block.l means the level of detail which is analyzing current(????I don't understand very well).Sj means the scalar value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if the volume data is not power of 2 for example 512*512*225,how should I divide the volume data?

Pad the non power of two dimensions symetrically with zeros to reach a power of 2 length.

The LOD formula is a bit confusing without knowing what each parameter and variable means. But if I had to make an educated guess I'd say that it relates the LoD to the on-screen size of the block, to limit the LoD resolution by the Nyquist limit.